# Faculty interview: 15 min. PPT explaining Teaching philosophy and Research Vision

Tags: faculty-application, presentation, interview

I have a faculty interview call that asks me to summarize the following two points in 15 minutes PPT. The interview will be on Zoom.

1. How would you describe your teaching philosophy? With examples from your previous teaching experience?
2. How do you think your research can help develop the research direction of the school, outlining vision and plans for the next three years?

Any suggestions will be highly appreciated as it is my first such interview.

Comment: You have to explain your teaching philosophy - we don’t know it and cannot guess. And as for how you implement and support the research direction - same thing. Slides though: clarity & brevity.

Comment: Well, what *is* your teaching philosophy? What did you research and what does the faculty you apply for research already? How does your work fit in. That's what you have to explain.

Comment: This might help you: https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/41891/72855

Answer (score 1):

On the first point, there are some questions you should consider.

- how do you lead students to have insights? Through in-class activities, assignments, projects, reading, essays, test taking? How much emphasis is placed on each aspect?
- are your assignments/projects/tests creative? Or merely regurgitation of the material?
- how do you account for the (expected) differences in learning style? Do you adapt your style to fit theirs?
- how much work outside of class is expected?
- how do you detect and respond to plagiarism?
- how do you deal with disruptive students?

Regarding research, what is the reputation of the school? of the department?

- What is their faculty known for? Theory vs lab vs simulation-based?
- Can you find collaborators? (on campus and elsewhere)
- Do you have collaborators outside of academia (National Labs, industry)?
- How much money do you need?
- Do you have special requirements?
- How much staffing is required?
- Can you use undergrads or grads or postdocs in your research?